# How do you make media queries work in outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

As far as I've read the mobile version of outlook supports media queries but when I try to send an html file(as text) it seems that the query is ignored. After sending the email and checking my phone I still get the desktop version of the document. Is there a different way of embedding the file? Internet searches show that it should work.

Edit: After looking at the source of the email it seems that outlook is in fact removing the query. Why is that?

Comment: Is this question about the mobile version of Outlook? Which version are you having the problem in?

Comment: I am sending the emails from the desktop version.

Comment: What is a "media query"? If you open the email on Outlook desktop, was the "query" removed? If not, the problem is with your mobile app and is off topic here. Please edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: [Media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) is a part of code that you can add to your html that will be executed if a condition is met. And yes it gets removed when I try to send my html as I've mentioned in the edit. I don't know how much clearer I can make it.

Comment: So this is HTML code in the email body? Like I asked earlier though, does the code get removed when you open the message in the desktop client rather than mobile? What about other email clients? Have you determined whether it is being removed on send, or on receipt?

Comment: The html file is being embedded into the email. I believe the codes is removed on send. It's seems to be taking only the basics from the styles tag like font, color, etc. It even ignores some inline attributes too (like hidden for example).